# php how to access variable inside function

Tags: php, variables, get

I have function, say:

```
//file file1.php 
class p{
  function a(){
    global$v1;        
    $v1='';   
    //some processing to $v1 here//
    return $v1;
  }
}
```

How to access $v1? ($v1 in `return $v1`)

This is my try (in another file) :

```
//file file2.php
include 'file1.php';
$obj=new p();
$print=$obj->a()->$v1;
echo $print;
```

Why doesn't it print anything?

Comment: First off, $v1 is __not__ a property of p(), so trying to use a fluent interface to access the $v1 property is meaningless

Comment: Second, You have $v1 as a global, so why not simply `echo $v1;`

Comment: Thirdly, learn a bit about OOP

Comment: hi @MarkBaker can you give me an example for my case? thanks

Comment: You may find this [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
class p{
  function a($v1){
            ///some processing to $v1 here//
            return $v1;
        }
    }
```

Then pass your variable as a argument to your function.

```
//file file2.php
$v1 = 'Test';

require 'file1.php';
$obj=new p();
$print=$obj->a($v1);
echo $print;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//file file1.php 
class p{
  protected $v1;

    public function setP($v1){
     $this->v1 = $v1;
    }

  public function getP(){

    $this->setP('');   
    ///some processing to $v1 here//
   return $this->v1;
   }
}

$obj = new p();
$print = $obj->getP();
echo $print;
?>
```